# Which step is wrong?

Tags: complex-numbers, fake-proofs

(1)$1=\sqrt{1}$

(2)$=\sqrt{-1×-1}$

(3)$=\sqrt{-1}×\sqrt{-1}$

(4)$=i×i=-1$

$1=-1$

Which step is wrong? I guess step 3 but I dont know why

Comment: Yes, you can't just go from (2) to (3), because you haven't proved that this power identity holds for complex numbers (and in fact this example proves that it doesn't if you define $\sqrt{}$ this way).

Answer (score 2):

The third step because $$\sqrt{-1}=\{i,-i\}$$ and we can not write $$\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}=i\cdot i.$$

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb C$, $$\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt a\sqrt b,$$
doesn't hold.